# Mouse cursor disappears in VLC when I unplug my G700 mouse

Tags: 16.04, vlc, cursor, xps

I encountered a strange problem\bug with VLC in Ubuntu 16.04.

I use the G700 mouse of Logitech (that can be used as either wireless or wired mouse).

When I start VLC (version 2.2.2) with the mouse connected and then I unplug the mouse (to use it as wireless), the cursor won't appear anymore in VLC (even when I move the mouse). I have to close and reopen VLC while the mouse is in wireless mode to solve this. Very annoying.

Anyone else encountered this?
(I use xps 13 9343)